# Program error ntdll!RtlQueryPerformanceCounter()

Tags: c++, fault

When I run this code :

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : sum.cpp
// Author      : Yordan Borisov
// Version     :
// Copyright   : MIT License
//
// Description : Sum bug numbers in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int _INT(char ch) {
    return ch - '0';
}
char _CHAR(int n) {
    return n + '0';
}

char* validateSize(int size_one, int size_two, char* _n_T, char*& _n_O) {
    if (size_one != size_two) {
        int diff = abs(size_one - size_two);
        int _less_Length = strlen((size_one > size_two ? _n_T : _n_O));
        char* tmp = new char[_less_Length + diff];
        strcpy(tmp, "\0");
        int _index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
            tmp[_index++] = '0';
        }
        tmp[_index] = '\0';
        for (int i = 0; i < _less_Length; i++) {
            tmp[_index++] = (size_one > size_two ? _n_T : _n_O)[i];
        }
        tmp[_index] = '\0';
        (size_one > size_two ? _n_T : _n_O) = tmp;
    }
    return _n_T;
}

char* sum(const char* numOne, const char* numTwo) {
    int size_one = strlen(numOne);
    int size_two = strlen(numTwo);
    char* _n_O = new char[size_one];
    char* _n_T = new char[size_two];
    strcpy(_n_O, numOne);
    strcpy(_n_T, numTwo);
    _n_T = validateSize(size_one, size_two, _n_T, _n_O);
    char* result = new char[size_one + 1];
    result[size_one] = '\0';
    int _CF = 0;
    int _increase = 0;
    for (long  i = (size_one > size_two ? size_one : size_two) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char chOne = _n_O[i];
        char chTwo = _n_T[i];
        int _sum = _INT(chOne) + _INT(chTwo) + _CF;
        _CF = _sum / 10;
        result[i] = _CHAR(_sum % 10);
        if (i == 0 && _CF > 0) {
            //in that case additional element in the result must be added.
            char _ch = _CHAR(_CF);
            char* _tmp_Pr = new char[1];
            _tmp_Pr[0] = _ch;
            _tmp_Pr[1] = '\0';
            _increase = 1;
            char* _tmp_R = strcat(_tmp_Pr, result);
            strcpy(result, _tmp_R);
        }
    }
    result[(size_one > size_two ? size_one : size_two) + _increase] = '\0';
    return result;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    cout
            << sum(
                    "147852369314785236936521548669522211478523693147852369365215486695222146521548221446521548221414785236931478523693652154866952221465215482214147852369314785236936521548669522214652154822141478523693147852369365215486695222114785236931478523693652154866952221465215482214465215482214147852369314785236936521548669522214652154822141478523693147852369365215486695222146521548221414785236931478523693652154866952221147852369314785236936521548669522214652154822144652154822141478523693147852369365215486695222146521548221414785236931478523693652154866952221465215482214147852369314785236936521548669522211478523693147852369365215486695222146521548221446521548221414785236931478523693652154866952221465215482214147852369314785236936521548669522214652154822141478523693147852369365215486695222114785236931478523693652154866952221465215482214465215482214147852369314785236936521548669522214652154822141478523693147852369365215486695222146521548221414785236931478523693652154866952221147852369314785236936521548669522214652154822144652154822141478523693147852369365215486695222146521548221414785236931478523693652154866952221465215482214",
                    "3652154632844521165000528563218221363652154632844521165000528563218221452154632844521165000528563218221436521546328445211650005285632182214365215463284452116500052856321822144365215463284452116500052856321822136365215463284452116500052856321822145215463284452116500052856321822143652154632844521165000528563218221436521546328445211650005285632182214436521546328445211650005285632182213636521546328445211650005285632182214521546328445211650005285632182214365215463284452116500052856321822143652154632844521165000528563218221443652154632844521165000528563218221363652154632844521165000528563218221452154632844521165000528563218221436521546328445211650005285632182214365215463284452116500052856321822144365215463284452116500052856321822136365215463284452116500052856321822145215463284452116500052856321822143652154632844521165000528563218221436521546328445211650005285632182214436521546328445211650005285632182213636521546328445211650005285632182214521546328445211650005285632182214365215463284452116500052856321822143652154632844521165000528563218221443652154632844521165000528563218221363652154632844521165000528563218221452154632844521165000528563218221436521546328445211650005285632182214365215463284452116500052856321822144")
            << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've got this exception:

```
Thread #1 0 (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault)   
    ntdll!RtlQueryPerformanceCounter() at 0x777531f6    
    ntdll!RtlQueryPerformanceCounter() at 0x77753431    
    ntdll!RtlpNtEnumerateSubKey() at 0x777f0f0e 
    ntdll!RtlUlonglongByteSwap() at 0x777aaa86  
    0x740000    
    ntdll!RtlQueryPerformanceCounter() at 0x77753431    
    towlower() at 0x7700ade8    
    towlower() at 0x7700ae43    
    msvcrt!_close() at 0x77013bb9   
    0x1 
    <...more frames...>
```

In the disassembly code on line 777764bc:

```
    ......... ...
777531c2:   dec     %esp
777531c3:   add     %dh,-0x75(%esi,%edx,1)
777531c7:   dec     %eax
777531c8:   push    %eax
777531c9:   xor     %ecx,(%esi)
777531cb:   mov     0x2(%esi),%cl
777531ce:   xor     0x1(%esi),%cl
777531d1:   xor     (%esi),%cl
777531d3:   cmp     %cl,0x3(%esi)
777531d6:   jne     0x777aab1a <ntdll!RtlUlonglongByteSwap+56842>
777531dc:   movzwl  (%esi),%ebx
777531df:   cmp     -0x2c(%ebp),%ebx
777531e2:   jb      0x77794568 <ntdll!RtlGetProcessHeaps+199>
777531e8:   lea     0x8(%esi),%ecx
777531eb:   mov     (%ecx),%edi
777531ed:   mov     %edi,-0x48(%ebp)
777531f0:   mov     0xc(%esi),%edx
777531f3:   mov     %edx,-0x68(%ebp)
777531f6:   mov     (%edx),%edx
777531f8:   mov     0x4(%edi),%edi
777531fb:   cmp     %edi,%edx
777531fd:   jne     0x7779455b <ntdll!RtlGetProcessHeaps+186>
77753203:   cmp     %ecx,%edx
77753205:   jne     0x7779455b <ntdll!RtlGetProcessHeaps+186>
7775320b:   sub     %ebx,0x78(%eax)
7775320e:   mov     0xb8(%eax),%eax
77753214:   test    %eax,%eax
77753216:   je      0x777532ed <ntdll!RtlQueryPerformanceCounter+2457>
7775321c:   movzwl  (%esi),%edi
7775321f:   mov     %eax,-0xb4(%ebp)
77753225:   mov     0x4(%eax),%ecx
77753228:   cmp     %ecx,%edi
7775322a:   jae     0x777537b3 <ntdll!RtlQueryPerformanceCounter+3679>
77753230:   mov     %edi,-0x8c(%ebp)
77753236:   mov     -0x8c(%ebp),%ecx
7775323c:   sub     0x14(%eax),%ecx
7775323f:   mov     %ecx,0x10(%ebp)
77753242:   cmpl    $0x0,0x8(%eax)
77753246:   je      0x7775324a <ntdll!RtlQueryPerformanceCounter+2294>
77753248:   add     %ecx,%ecx
7775324a:   mov     %ecx,%edi
7775324c:   shl     $0x2,%edi
7775324f:   mov     0x20(%eax),%ecx
77753252:   lea     (%edi,%ecx,1),%edx
77753255:   mov     (%edx),%ecx
77753257:   mov     %ecx,-0x38(%ebp)
7775325a:   decl    0xc(%eax)
7775325d:   mov     0x4(%eax),%ecx
77753260:   dec     %ecx
77753261:   cmp     %ecx,-0x8c(%ebp)
......... ...
```

Comment: That call stack is complete nonsense.  You need a better debugger, aim for one that doesn't say "Segmentation fault".  The code corrupts the heap, at least an off-by-one bug in char* _n_O = new char[size_one]; is easily visible but there are likely to be more.

Comment: You might as well remove that huge licence text, because it's (a) taking up space, and (b) redundant, given that you licenced your code to us under CC-by-SA 3.0 by posting it here.

Comment: Also this code is completely unreadable and have you tried debugging it to produce a [MCVE]?

Comment: Well I am giving you everything as input and you can run the program and see what is the output :)

Comment: And also I am using mingw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the problem : it was in the

```
char* result = new char[(size_one > size_two ? size_one : size_two) + 1];
result[(size_one > size_two ? size_one : size_two)] = '\0';
```

and I was using :

```
char* result = new char[size_one + 1];
result[size_one] = '\0';
```

which apperantly is wrong because the `size_one` is smaller that `size_two`.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite the code using std::string instead of char*

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : sum.cpp
// Author      : Yordan Borisov
// Version     :
// Copyright   : MIT License
//
// Description : Sum bug numbers in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int _INT(char ch) {
    return ch - '0';
}
char _CHAR(int n) {
    return n + '0';
}

void validateSize(int size_one, int size_two, string& _n_T, string& _n_O) {
    if (size_one != size_two) {
        int diff = abs(size_one - size_two);
        string tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
            tmp.append("0");
        }
        tmp.append((size_one > size_two ? _n_T : _n_O));
        (size_one > size_two ? _n_T : _n_O).clear();
        (size_one > size_two ? _n_T : _n_O).append(tmp);
    }
}

string sum(const string numOne, const string numTwo) {
    int size_one = numOne.length();
    int size_two = numTwo.length();
    string _n_O(numOne);
    string _n_T(numTwo);
    validateSize(size_one, size_two, _n_T, _n_O);

    string result = "";

    int _CF = 0;

    for (long i = (size_one > size_two ? size_one : size_two) - 1; i >= 0;
            i--) {
        char chOne = _n_O[i];
        char chTwo = _n_T[i];
        int _sum = _INT(chOne) + _INT(chTwo) + _CF;
        _CF = _sum / 10;
        result.append(string(1, _CHAR(_sum % 10)));
        if (i == 0 && _CF > 0) {
            //in that case additional element in the result must be added.
            string tmp(1, _CHAR(_CF));

            result.append(tmp);

        }
    }
    reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string res =
            sum(
                    "147852369314785236936521548669522211478523693147852369365215486695222146521548221446521548221414785236931478523693652154866952221465215482214147852369314785236936521548669522214652154822141478523693147852369365215486695222114785236931478523693652154866952221465215482214465215482214147852369314785236936521548669522214652154822141478523693147852369365215486695222146521548221414785236931478523693652154866952221147852369314785236936521548669522214652154822144652154822141478523693147852369365215486695222146521548221414785236931478523693652154866952221465215482214147852369314785236936521548669522211478523693147852369365215486695222146521548221446521548221414785236931478523693652154866952221465215482214147852369314785236936521548669522214652154822141478523693147852369365215486695222114785236931478523693652154866952221465215482214465215482214147852369314785236936521548669522214652154822141478523693147852369365215486695222146521548221414785236931478523693652154866952221147852369314785236936521548669522214652154822144652154822141478523693147852369365215486695222146521548221414785236931478523693652154866952221465215482214",
                    "3652154632844521165000528563218221363652154632844521165000528563218221452154632844521165000528563218221436521546328445211650005285632182214365215463284452116500052856321822144365215463284452116500052856321822136365215463284452116500052856321822145215463284452116500052856321822143652154632844521165000528563218221436521546328445211650005285632182214436521546328445211650005285632182213636521546328445211650005285632182214521546328445211650005285632182214365215463284452116500052856321822143652154632844521165000528563218221443652154632844521165000528563218221363652154632844521165000528563218221452154632844521165000528563218221436521546328445211650005285632182214365215463284452116500052856321822144365215463284452116500052856321822136365215463284452116500052856321822145215463284452116500052856321822143652154632844521165000528563218221436521546328445211650005285632182214436521546328445211650005285632182213636521546328445211650005285632182214521546328445211650005285632182214365215463284452116500052856321822143652154632844521165000528563218221443652154632844521165000528563218221363652154632844521165000528563218221452154632844521165000528563218221436521546328445211650005285632182214365215463284452116500052856321822144");
    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and it is working but it is slow. So I suppose the problem is with the allocation of the char pointers.